# How do I program on/off button for Android?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

i'm trying to make an on and off button for my background music. music starts right away. music turns off when i press off button but when i press on button it force closes. please help

```
mp=MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.islandsong);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();

    onButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp==null){
                mp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    offButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mp!=null){
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                mp = null; 
            }               
        }
    });
```

Comment: `if (mp==null){
                mp.start();
            }` That isn't really what you want.

Comment: post the stacktrace. you could use a toogle button

Comment: Don't debug through stackoverflow. A force close means that you should check your logcat to see _why_ it crashed. If the stacktrace confuses you even after researching it, post here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong approach. You should check if the music player is playing, if so stop it.

```
try { 
   if(mp.isPlaying()){
       mp.stop();
       mp.release(); 
    } 
 } catch(Exception ex) { 
   ex.printStackTrace() 
 }
```

**Update**
You need to edit your code to following if you want to play and stop the Media Player

```
onButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (!mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.start();
            }
        }
    });

    offButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {           
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try { 
                if(mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.stop();
                mp.release(); 
                } 
              } catch(Exception ex) { 
                 ex.printStackTrace() 
              }               
        }
```

This code will ensure that Media Player play song only if it is not playing and stop only if it is playing.

Comment: Rohan Kandwal is right. If you do this: **mp = null**, then mp won't be accessed anymore, unless you don't recreate it (once set to null, it's lost forever). +1 for giving the right answer.